# Fixing X terminal emulator window title

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have some old program information that is being displayed on my title bar. I am unable to clear it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is the title still wrong after a reboot?

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the title with

```
printf "^[]2;^G"
```

Where `^[` is <kbd>Ctrl-V ESCape</kbd>, and `^G` is <kbd>Ctrl-V Ctrl-G</kbd>.

You really should figure out where the title comes from.

Install `xttitle` and read `man xttitle` if you want to manipulate the title.

Comment: Could you tell me why there is a rectangle and 4 circles icon in front of the username?

Comment: You must not ask a 2nd question in the comments. 2nd questions, and their ( possible) wonderful answers are not scanned by the AskUbuntu indexing system, and do not help future users.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the support, I have found the problem, I had some things written in my bashrc under "xterm", I removed it and all was ok.

I am not sure how it got there in the first place. Maybe I have hit a shortcut key. I am not sure.

Regards